# Extending Eigen::EigenBase with operator()

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I would like to use MatrixXd class for meshes with offsets (0.5, 0) and (0, 0.5). In mathematical formulas, velocity is calculated between cells i,i+1, and this is written as vel(i+0.5,j). I would like to introduce syntax like this one:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

int main() {
  Eigen::MatrixXd m = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(5,5);
  // Want to use similar syntax:
  // m(0, 1.5) = 1.0;
  // and
  // m(3.5, 1) = 2.0;
  // Instead of:
  m(0, 2) = 1.0;
  m(4, 1) = 2.0;
}
```

Using [EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_Plugins.html) like this one:

```
inline Scalar& operator()(int r, int c) {
  return Base::operator()(r, c);
}

inline Scalar& operator()(double r, int c) {
  return Base::operator()(int(r + 0.5), c);
}

inline Scalar& operator()(int r, double c) {
  return Base::operator()(r, int(c + 0.5));
}
```

However, this approach:

1. Works only for only X-axis or only Y-axis offset, not both at the same time.
2. Works only for specific offset hardcoded into plugin.
3. Breaks some internal Eigen convections, which can be [demostrated](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicSparseSystems.html) by trying to compile BiCG example with IncompleteLUT preconditioner:

```
  int n = 10000;
  VectorXd x(n), b(n);
  SparseMatrix<double> A(n,n);
  /* ... fill A and b ... */ 
  BiCGSTAB<SparseMatrix<double>,IncompleteLUT<double>> solver;
  solver.compute(A);
  x = solver.solve(b);
```

Causes following errors:

```
term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
'Eigen::SparseMatrix<double,1,int>::insertBackByOuterInnerUnordered': function does not take 1 arguments
```

Adding operator()(double offset_col, double offset_row) to adress second issue like this:

```
double r_offset = -0.5, c_offset = -0.5;

inline void set_r_offset(double val) { r_offset = val; }
inline void set_c_offset(double val) { c_offset = val; }

inline double get_r_offset() { return r_offset; }
inline double get_c_offset() { return c_offset; }

inline Scalar& operator()(double r, double c) {
//  double r_offset = -0.5, c_offset = -0.5;
  return Base::operator()(int(r - r_offset), int(c - c_offset));
}
```

This causes illegal free:

```
==6035== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==6035==    at 0x4C30D3B: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: aligned_free (Memory.h:177)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: conditional_aligned_free<true> (Memory.h:230)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: conditional_aligned_delete_auto<double, true> (Memory.h:416)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: resize (DenseStorage.h:406)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: resize (PlainObjectBase.h:293)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: resize_if_allowed<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, double, double> (AssignEvaluator.h:720)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: call_dense_assignment_loop<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double> > (AssignEvaluator.h:734)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: run (AssignEvaluator.h:879)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: call_assignment_no_alias<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double> > (AssignEvaluator.h:836)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: call_assignment<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >, Eigen::internal::assign_op<double, double> > (AssignEvaluator.h:804)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: call_assignment<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1>, Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > > (AssignEvaluator.h:782)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: _set<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > > (PlainObjectBase.h:710)
==6035==    by 0x4E4224A: operator=<Eigen::CwiseNullaryOp<Eigen::internal::scalar_constant_op<double>, Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> > > (Matrix.h:225)
==6035==    by 0x11044C: main (Runner.cpp:16)
==6035==  Address 0x2e642f73726573 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

If offsets are not introduced as class members, but are local variables in operator(), no errors are detected by valgrind.

Is it possible to implement new MatrixXd::operator()(double, double) with settable offsets?

EDIT:
Operator() is defined in a parent class [DenseCoeffsBase](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseCoeffsBase_3_01Derived_00_01ReadOnlyAccessors_01_4.html#ab3dbba4a15d0fe90185d2900e5ef0fd1):

```
EIGEN_DEVICE_FUNC
EIGEN_STRONG_INLINE CoeffReturnType operator()(Index row, Index col) const
{
   eigen_assert(row >= 0 && row < rows()
       && col >= 0 && col < cols());
   return coeff(row, col);
}
```

Comment: First of all, I think overloading `operator()` with `(double, double)` is a bad idea. If you really need this, I'd suggest wrapping a `MatrixXd` object inside a custom class. Regarding your error, please post a [mre]!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, I see one problem with your operator which returns reference to temporary object of Scalar:

```
inline Scalar& operator()(double r, double c) {
    //  double r_offset = -0.5, c_offset = -0.5;
    return Base::operator()(int(r - r_offset), int(c - c_offset));
}
```

So you should return Scalar by copy.

Could you share code of Base::operator()(int(r - r_offset), int(c - c_offset));?

Comment: Added answer to original post.
Not sure that returning copy is an optimal solution. Originally, i just copied a at() method from [Tutorial example](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-3.2/TopicCustomizingEigen.html). It returned reference, so I also tried it.
EDIT:
No, won't work. I need reference for this code: `vel(0.5, 0.5) = 1.0;`.
Without reference, error `'=': left operand must be l-value` pops up.

Comment: @Kirikus Regarding your error, please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because i cannot help you without it!